# Getting the default titleTextAttributes for UINavigationBar

Tags: ios, uinavigationbar

I want to use a custom titleView for the navigation bar in my app, so that it can be user editable. I'm trying to get the default font/alignment/etc so I can apply this to my new view, so it looks the same as a normal nav bar title.

I'm using

```
NSMutableDictionary *myDict = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithDictionary:self.navigationController.navigationBar.titleTextAttributes];
NSLog(@"%@", myDict);
```

but this just shows an empty dictionary. I've looked at other answers on stackoverflow which suggest this should return the default font.

Am I doing something wrong? Or has this changed in iOS7?

**EDIT**: Thanks to caglar below, I've updated my code:

```
// Get the default title label
UILabel *navigationTitleLabel;
for (UIView *sv in self.navigationController.navigationBar.subviews)
{
    if (sv.subviews.count > 0 && [sv.subviews[0] isKindOfClass:[UILabel class]])
    {
        navigationTitleLabel = (UILabel *)sv.subviews[0];
        break;
    }
}

// Set the new text field to have the same attributes as the default title label
textField.font = navigationTitleLabel.font;
textField.textColor = navigationTitleLabel.textColor;
textField.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
self.navigationItem.titleView = textField;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can access the subviews of navigation bar, because `UINavigationBar` is subclass of `UIView`.
This is for iOS 7. In older versions subviews orders may be different than this one. However, idea is same, go over subviews of `UINavigationBar` and reach the title.

```
for (UIView *sv in self.navigationController.navigationBar.subviews)
{
    if (sv.subviews.count > 0 && [sv.subviews[0] isKindOfClass:[UILabel class]])
    {
        self.navigationTitleLabel = (UILabel *)sv.subviews[0];
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks very much for your help. I've used your suggested code to find the UILabel in the navigation bar, then I take the font properties directly from there and put them on my new view (which is a UITextField).